# static method in a class having values are not printing using java?

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I'm Printing values of static method but its not printing outside of main method/blocks.

This is my code:

```
public class SampleCheck {

// Java 1.8 Version
static void fun() {
    System.out.println("Fun Method");
}

static void run() {
    System.out.println("run Method");
}

SampleCheck() {
    System.out.println("sample Constructor");
}

{
    System.out.println("Empty Block Method");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You are in main method");
    System.out.println("ONLY main method executing");
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you calling your static methods?

Comment: @TheLostMind,I thought of static block and static method is same,sorry to post ,now i got to know.

Comment: to call method ``className.methodName()`` you need to follow that

Answer (score 0):

I thought of static block and static method same so sorry for that ,now right code is like this

```
public class SampleCheck {
    // Java 1.8 Version
    static void fun() {
        System.out.println("Fun Method");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("static block");
    }

    static void run() {
        System.out.println("run Method");
    }

    SampleCheck() {
        System.out.println("sample Constructor");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Empty Block Method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("You are in main method");
        System.out.println("ONLY main method executing");
    }
}
```

Comment: just call as ``SampleCheck.run();``

Answer (score 0):

If you have static block like below code, it will print while loading the class it will execute the static block:

```
static {
        System.out.println("print inside staic block");
    }
```

If you have static method, it will not print unless you call it .

```
static void run(){
        System.out.println("print inside staic method");
    }
```